# How can I use BABE's randomness in my parachain?

Tags: runtime, babe, randomness

I would like to use BABE's randomness for some on-chain logic. IIUC using BABE inside a parachain's runtime is not recommended good practice because there's no fallback for producing blocks if no collator is found, so parachain runtime developers must use Aura.

Is there a way for me to benefit from BABE's randomness in my parachain's runtime, perhaps from the relay chain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the randomness from the relay chain. It is currently not that easy, but you should be able to do it in the following way:

In your runtime:

```
impl cumulus_parachain_system::Config for Runtime {
    type OnSystemEvent = MySystemEventHandler;
    ...
}
```

Wherever `MySystemEventHandler` is implemented:

```
impl OnSystemEvent for MySystemEventHandler {
    fn on_validation_data(data: &PersistedValidationData) {
        let proof = cumulus_parachain_system::RelayChainStateProof::new(my_para_id, data.relay_parent_storage_root, cumulus_parachain_system::Pallet::relay_state_proof()).expect("Invalid relay chain proof");

       use cumulus_primitives_core::relay_chain::well_known_keys as relay_well_known_keys;
       let randomness = proof.read_entry::<schnorrkel::Randomness>(relay_well_known_keys::CURRENT_BLOCK_RANDOMNESS);
    }
    ..
}
```

There exists three different types of randomness that BABE can provide to you. See [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5abf6c8a015fac28d33967800da7c5c8d53002e3/frame/babe/src/randomness.rs#L27-L121) for a description of each of them.

Comment: Can you give a working example how to put the randomness source inside a custom pallet? Can you give examples how all of these https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5abf6c8a015fac28d33967800da7c5c8d53002e3/frame/babe/src/randomness.rs#L27-L121 are used?

Comment: How can I include `schnorrkel` in my runtime?

Comment: Check the answer below by Sacha.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Moonbeam/Moonriver has a way to do this using a runtime API for client side VRF verification (see: [full code snip](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/4e2a5785424be6faa01cd14e90155d9d2ec734ee/runtime/moonbase/src/lib.rs#L1110-L1126) and [original PR](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/pull/1376)):

```rust
pub struct BabeDataGetter;
impl pallet_randomness::GetBabeData<u64, Option<Hash>> for BabeDataGetter {
    // Tolerate panic here because only ever called in inherent (so can be omitted)
    fn get_epoch_index() -> u64 {
        relay_chain_state_proof()
            .read_optional_entry(relay_chain::well_known_keys::EPOCH_INDEX)
            .ok()
            .flatten()
            .expect("expected to be able to read epoch index from relay chain state proof")
    }
    fn get_epoch_randomness() -> Option<Hash> {
        relay_chain_state_proof()
            .read_optional_entry(relay_chain::well_known_keys::ONE_EPOCH_AGO_RANDOMNESS)
            .ok()
            .flatten()
    }
}

impl pallet_randomness::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type AddressMapping = moonbeam_runtime_common::IntoAddressMapping;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type BabeDataGetter = BabeDataGetter; // <--- used here
    ...
 }
```